# Application Error on my Heroku page, even my app build succeeded

Tags: node.js, heroku, passport.js

Created on MongoDB/Atlas database system. I successfully run my app locally but when I push the app to Heroku i get an application error message which is:

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
> served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
> You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>
> heroku logs --tail

When I look at the logs:

```
2021-05-10T13:47:26.214536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-10T13:47:30.291660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-05-10T13:47:34.377424+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-05-10T13:47:34.377459+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-05-10T13:47:34.377460+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430435+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:86
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430437+00:00 app[web.1]: if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430438+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430439+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430439+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430439+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:86:34)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430440+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Strategy (/app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430440+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:60:14)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430441+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430441+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430442+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430442+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430443+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-05-10T13:47:34.430443+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2021-05-10T13:47:34.513199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-10T13:47:34.609472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-10T13:47:35.401133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-lowlands-39265.herokuapp.com request_id=04ac407e-ed22-4211-8600-a326bdc1d6c8 fwd="82.222.132.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T13:47:35.696159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-lowlands-39265.herokuapp.com request_id=11a57d28-d3c5-4a7a-8f2d-6187ac3997ec fwd="82.222.132.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T14:08:33.993147+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-lowlands-39265.herokuapp.com request_id=6d9f98e3-cfe2-40b2-a68e-bbac56a743f2 fwd="82.222.132.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T14:08:34.290006+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-lowlands-39265.herokuapp.com request_id=0c1a084b-0286-4204-8e13-3413bf93e5ac fwd="82.222.132.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T14:14:27.859879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-lowlands-39265.herokuapp.com request_id=121f0bcf-5253-40d3-91fb-d5421ec0e4d8 fwd="82.222.132.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T14:14:28.345855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-lowlands-39265.herokuapp.com request_id=44bd06c7-dbee-48f3-8389-211ccd2d3ee1 fwd="82.222.132.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have no problems with Procfile or some other errors while running on my computer. I tried to change the GoogleStrategy callbackURL adresses in app.js and Google Cloud Platform with my heroku web address. But it doesn't work again. I couldn't figure out.

Thank you for your helps in advance.

Comment: How have you configured your environment variables ?

Comment: DOTENV Approach is very useful for me. I just needed to arrange heroku settings as you said. Thank you so much for help @JaganKaartik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your app can't find the `Google Client ID`.

> TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option

It seems like you haven't configured your `.env` variables properly in Heroku. The solution is really simple.

1. `DOTENV Approach`

If you've defined your `.env` in this manner,

```
MONGO_URL="xxx.....xxx"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="xx......xxx"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="xxx.....xxx"
```

and in your `passport-setup` and `db-setup` you are using `dotenv` as,

```
require('dotenv').config();
.
.
.
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy
  (
    {
      clientID : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL : '/auth/google/callback'
    },
.
.
.
```

then, you must have declared a `.env` file in your project's root directory on your computer.

Your `.gitignore` file might have `.env` mentioned, as this is the standard way of doing it (You don't push env variables to public/team repositories).

The reason it works on your computer is that, the app has context of the environment variables. In `Heroku` since `.env` file isn't present, the app doesn't know where to find them.

All you have to do is add your environment variables to Heroku. Just go to settings in Heroku Dashboard, go to the `Config variables` menu. Add your env variables in the format shown below. Restart the dyno.

[image]

This would solve your issue.

2. `NON-DOTENV Approach`

If you are using any arbitrary file eg. `keys.js` or something from which you're exporting the respective secrets. Example,

```
const keys = require('../config/keys');
.
.
.
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy
  (
    {
      clientID : keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret : keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL : '/auth/google/callback'
    },
.
.
.
```

If you are using a config file similar to `keys.js` etc, then check if that file exists on Heroku.

If you were using `dotenv`, I'm sure this answer will solve your issue. In case you were not using `dotenv`, I'll give you an updated answer.

(BONUS)

For the warning,

> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale past a single process.

You could use `cookie-session` (client side session) instead of server-side session.